# Can we set pre deployment approvals in deploy stage YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Can we set pre deployment conditions in deploy stage YAML ?

I have two stages in my YAML pipeline Azure DevOps (we restrict team to use classic pipelines).
I want to know whether we have possibility to set Pre-Deployment Approvals in YAMl for Deploy Stage?

Answer (score 3):

> Can we set pre deployment conditions in deploy stage YAML ?

Yes. You can define the approval in Environment(**Pipelines -> Environment**).

Here are the steps:

1. Create Environment.
2. Navigate to **Environment -> Approvals and checks**. Then you can add the Approvals in the environment.

[image]

3. Use the Environment in your Deploy Stage.

For example:

```
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    environment: envname
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
           xxxx
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Create and target an environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops#approvals)

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the answers which together provide all the information but miss bits of info each:

###### There is no concept of manual stage approval like in Classic Release pipelines (called ***pre-deployment approval***) for YAML azure pipelines

as is indicated by the official MS doc extract provided by @GeralexGR.

###### The only workaround officially documented to get the "same" result is to create an ***environment*** which you protect with an ***approval***, and then make your stage use this environment

in order to effectively create a manual approval on your stage.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean in the release pipeline? You can set your pre-deployment approvals on your release pipelines using gates or an approval from a user.

[image: predeployment-approvals]

Configuration of pre-deployment approvals.

[image]

If you mean deployment approvals on the build pipeline, you could configure a logic for the build run (specific branch, conditions to evaluate variables and booleans before the run)

As stated in the documentation:

> Approvals and other checks are not defined in the yaml file. Users
> modifying the pipeline yaml file cannot modify the checks performed
> before start of a stage. Administrators of resources manage checks
> using the web interface of Azure Pipelines.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass